# Android Gridview fastscroll

Tags: android, gridview

I have a Gridview with fastscroll enabled, but set to not always show the scrollbar.

However, when I click the right of the screen, it fastscrolls even when the scrollbar is not showing. How do I make it so it only scrolls when it shows the scrollbar? Thanks.

Comment: why not `yourGridView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);` when you show scrollbar and `yourGridView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);` when you hide it?

Comment: I mean I have gridview.FastScrollEnabled = true; and gridview.FastScrollAlwaysVisible = false. The scrollbar only appears when I started to scroll, but the scrolltrack, although invisible, is always sensitive.

Comment: what behaviour you want then ?

Comment: I want fast scroll to only be enabled when the fast scrollbar is visible and the user drags it. If the Gridview is not scrolling, the scrollbar is not visible - if I click the right of the screen at that moment, it should not fast scroll. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed hiding scrollbar doesn't unable/disable fastscroll.
I found a solution but it's kinda ugly ... you enable fastcroll only when list has been scrolled before, so the scrollbar is visible, and you disable it when it stop.

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                list.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
            }else {
                list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. When I start scrolling, the fast scrollbar does appear, but when I click on it, it seems to trigger a 'scroll state idle' and the fast scrollbar is not longer visible. Hence, it never fast scrolls.